# I can't fetch data from the doInBackground method in AsyncTask Subclass

Tags: java, android-asynctask

I'm trying to fetch earthquake data in my app and got my app stopped working. there is no error in my code. even I added internet permission. but when fetching data I think this error occurs. I've debugged but couldn't find the problem.

Logcat:

> 2021-03-27 15:23:32.118 9533-9560/com.example.quakereportapp
> E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da 2021-03-27
> 15:23:32.118 9533-9560/com.example.quakereportapp E/eglCodecCommon:
> glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
> ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1 2021-03-27 15:23:37.091
> 9533-9533/com.example.quakereportapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
> EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.quakereportapp, PID: 9533
> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
> at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1513)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.blockGuardOnNetwork(Platform.java:415)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.shutdownAndFreeSslNative(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1005)
> at com.android.org.conscrypt.ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.close(ConscryptFileDescriptorSocket.java:1000)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.Util.closeQuietly(Util.java:86)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.deallocate(StreamAllocation.java:256)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.StreamAllocation.connectionFailed(StreamAllocation.java:293)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.close(HttpEngine.java:445)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:509)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:407)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:538)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getResponseCode(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:105)
> at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:26)
> at com.example.quakereportapp.QueryUtils.makeHttpRequest(QueryUtils.java:82)
> at com.example.quakereportapp.QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(QueryUtils.java:35)
> at com.example.quakereportapp.MainActivity.updateUi(MainActivity.java:27)
> at com.example.quakereportapp.MainActivity.access$100(MainActivity.java:14)
> at com.example.quakereportapp.MainActivity$EarthQuakeAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:58)
> at com.example.quakereportapp.MainActivity$EarthQuakeAsyncTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:33)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:695)
> at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:180)
> at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:712)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)

My AsyncTask Sub-Class

```
private void updateUi(List<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquake = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(url);
    EarthquakeAdapter earthquakeAdapterArrayAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(this, earthquake);
    listView.setAdapter(earthquakeAdapterArrayAdapter);
}
private class EarthQuakeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, List<Earthquake>> {
 
    @Override
    protected  ArrayList<Earthquake> doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ArrayList<Earthquake> result = QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(urls[0]);
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Earthquake> result) {
        updateUi(result);
    }
```

My JSON Extractor method from QueryUtils Class

```
private static ArrayList<Earthquake> extractFeatureFromJson(String earthquakeJSON) {
    // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(earthquakeJSON)) {
        return null;
    }

    ArrayList<Earthquake> earthquakes = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        JSONObject baseJsonResponse = new JSONObject(earthquakeJSON);
        JSONArray earthquakeArray = baseJsonResponse.getJSONArray("features");

        for (int i = 0; i < earthquakeArray.length(); i++) {
            //creates object from the given array
            JSONObject currentEarthquake = earthquakeArray.getJSONObject(i);
            //stores all the data from properties to properties object
            JSONObject properties = currentEarthquake.getJSONObject("properties");
            //here we assign the value of the specified keys from the properties
            String magnitude = properties.getString("mag");
            String location = properties.getString("place");
            long time = properties.getLong("time");
            //and now we create a new earthquake in every loop
            Earthquake earthquake = new Earthquake(magnitude, location, time);
            //finally we add it to the earthquakes list
            earthquakes.add(earthquake);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
    }
    return earthquakes;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception is thrown because you are calling your API from the main thread. The problem in your code is your are calling your API twice. Once in `doInBackground` and then again in `updateUi`.
Remove the call to `QueryUtils.fetchEarthquakeData(url)` from `updateUi`, it should look like this.

```
private void updateUi(List<Earthquake> earthquakes) {
    listView = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    EarthquakeAdapter earthquakeAdapterArrayAdapter = new EarthquakeAdapter(this, earthquakes);
    listView.setAdapter(earthquakeAdapterArrayAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Tell me about using Arraylist<E> instead of using List<E> for AsyncTask Parameters and to the methods such as DoInBackground, onPostExecute, and updateUI, Is there any difference?

Comment: List<E> is an interface and ArrayList<E> is an implementation of List<E>.
In general you should declare all your methods and parameters to receive List<E>. You can then pass ArrayList<E> wherever List<E> is required.